# Why is pylint unable to find this package's module(s)?

Tags: python, pylint

I'm currently working with pylint, and I'm getting an error when I lint the single file (repro below). I'm using the azure sdk, but that is just the package I'm referencing, that shouldn't be significant here.

### Repro

```
$ mkdir pylinttesting && cd pylinttesting
$ python3 -m venv venv
$ . venv/bin/activate
$ pip3 install azure==2.0.0rc6
$ echo 'from azure import mgmt' > app.py
```

Running this script file causes no issues (`python3 app.py`)

#### pylint output

Even though this is totally valid and runs/imports without error, pylint still complains about it. Relevant output below (cut down for brevity)...

```
E:  1, 0: No name 'mgmt' in module 'azure' (no-name-in-module)

External dependencies
---------------------
::

    azure (app)
```

But! If I run this little snippet (in the same virtual environment)...

```
import os
import pkgutil
import azure

package_path = os.path.dirname(azure.__file__)
[print(name) for _, name, _ in pkgutil.iter_modules([package_path])]
```

... I get the following output...

```
batch
common
mgmt
servicebus
servicemanagement
storage
```

So obviously the `mgmt` module lives in the `azure` package. But I'm wondering why pylint doesn't pick that up?

It's also worth noting that if I do `from azure import common` (common is another module in the package), pylint doesn't throw the error.

Any thoughts on why pylint may be unhappy with this `mgmt` module in the package?

**EDIT**: pylint version information...

```
pylint 1.6.5, 
astroid 1.4.9
Python 3.6.0 (default, Dec 24 2016, 00:01:50) 
[GCC 4.2.1 Compatible Apple LLVM 8.0.0 (clang-800.0.42.1)]
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are using Pylint version that does not (yet) support [`declare_namespace` for creating namespaces](https://github.com/Azure/azure-sdk-for-python/blob/master/azure-servicebus/azure/__init__.py). What are the version of pylint/astroid used by you?

See https://github.com/PyCQA/pylint/issues/687 for similar issue and link to code which supports this namespace creation.

Keep in mind that Pylint actually does not run Python code during analysis, so most of non-standard (non-inferable) constructs have to be supported by writing custom code.

Comment: I've added the pylint version information into the question. So there is no "workaround" here then? I guess I could ignore this rule..? Or I could clone from github to get the apparent branch that has support for this..? Seems like those are my options if I have it correct? Thanks for your answer!

Comment: @ThomasStringer Yes, it's problematic - Pylint does not execute Python code so it has no chance to know what's going on under the hood. Understanding for this construct had to be implemented explicitly in Pylint's code. While this feature is ready, it seems like this it wasn't yet shipped. We plan to ship 1.7.0 as soon as possible, but until then, if you want to have it, you'll need to use `pylint` and `astroid` from master branch of repository.

Comment: Perfect! pylint 1.7 and asteroid 1.5 worked like a charm! Thanks!